# push в многомерном, ассоциативном массиве

Tags: javascript, ajax, массивы

Как на JavaScript реализовать следующее?

В цикле for идет проверка элементов html, и вот так должны выглядеть первые шаги цикла:

1) Проверка значений первого элемента, первое значение равно `num_1`, создается элемент ассоциативный массив:

```
{
   num_1:{val_1: val_2}
}
```

2) Проверка значений второго элемента, если первое значение равно `num_1`, добавляется новый элемент:

```
{
   num_1:{val_1: val_2,
          val_3: val_4}
}
```

и так далее. Иначе говоря надо пушить в конец ассоциативного массива новую ассоциацию. Нужен именно метод работы с массивом. Простой .push работает только с обычным массивом.

**upd:**

Если проще сказать, то нужен аналог вот такого кода на PHP:

```
$array[num_1][] = [val_1 => val_2]
$array[num_1][] = [val_3 => val_4]
```

Comment: _"и так далее."_ -- какое условие прекращения цикла?

Comment: @Stack Имеется в виду что идет проверка остальных элементов html, и если значение num_1, то добавляется новая ассоциация.

Comment: @Denis Где здесь у вас массив?

Comment: @VladfromMoscow тут у меня ассоциативный массив

Comment: в яваскрипте нет ассоциативных массивов, следовательно и работать с объектами как с массивами нельзя

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Судя по всему вы хотите просто добавить новое свойство со значением в объект, это реализуется следующим образом

```
var obj = {
   num_1:{val_1: val_2}
};

obj['num_1']['val_3'] = val_4;
```

результат

```
{
    num_1:
    {
        val_1: val_2,
        val_3: val_4
    }
}
```

Comment: Хм, несколько раз пробовал такую реализацию, но постоянно выдавало ошибку. Но да, это то что надо.

Comment: @Denis, надо просто смотреть что именно делали и в чем ошибка была. В любом случае как я сказал в комментариях, так как в яваскрипте нет ассоциативных массивов, то и работать с объектами как с массивами нельзя.